# removing encoding "UTF8": 0x00 chars from pandas dataframe for psycopg2 cursor

Tags: pandas, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert rows into a Postgresq database using the following code I grabbed somewhere in SO:

```
def to_sql(engine, df, table, if_exists='fail', sep='\t', encoding='utf8',
    schema='public', dtypes_sql=None, verbose=False):
    # Create Table
    ## istruzioni diverse se le colonne hanno dtypes diversi
    if verbose==True:
        print("Scrivo tabella targhe su tabella di schema {}".format(schema))
    if dtypes_sql is None:
        df[:0].to_sql(table, engine, if_exists=if_exists,schema=schema, index=False)
    else:
        df[:0].to_sql(table, engine, if_exists=if_exists,schema=schema, index=False,dtype=dtypes_sql)
    # Prepare data
    output = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(output, sep=sep, header=False, encoding=encoding, index=False)
    output.seek(0)

    # Insert data
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #handling different schemas:
    if schema in ['public','dbo']:
        cursor.copy_from(output, table, sep=sep, null='')

    else:
        new_table = schema + "." + table
        cursor.copy_from(output, new_table, sep=sep, null='')
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    if verbose==True:
        print("Saved")
    return None
```

The data was read from a dataframe that was originally read from a latin1 encoding file. I tried the following to clean out my original DataFrame but without any success:

```
input_file_df.replace(to_replace=b'\x00',value=' ', inplace=True,regex=True)
input_file_df.replace(to_replace="\x00", value=" ",inplace=True)
input_file_df.where(pd.notnull(input_file_df), None,inplace=True)
```

I would like to know:

1. how can I remove rows containing 0x00 from DataFrame:
2. if there is any way to skip bad rows in bulkinser;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the null in pandas data frame can be performed as follows:

```
import re
re_null = re.compile(pattern='\x00')
input_file_df.replace(regex=re_null,value=' ', inplace=True)
```

this would avoid the 0x00 issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strip('\x00')`:

```
b = b'caf\xc3\xa9\x00\x00';
print(b.decode('utf8').strip('\x00'))
```

or `replace('\x00', ' ')`:

```
b = b'caf\xc3\xa9\x00\x00';
print(b.decode('utf8').replace('\x00', ' '))
```

---

Outputs

```
café
```